# Using local system's .bash_profile and .vimrc on remote systems

Tags: ssh, scp, alias, bashrc, vimrc

Risking asking a possibly duplicate here but could not get any relevant answers.
I wish to use my local system's `.bash_profile` and `.vimrc` on all the remote hosts I log in to. Is there an easy way to temporarily use them on the remote hosts or to copy the files aliasing ssh clubbed with scp somehow that I don't have to copy them manually every-time.

Thanks.

Comment: People who rely on `.vimrc` or `.bash_profile` tricks usually don't manage many systems.

Comment: @kubanczyk I do and I like to have my alias and customizations available on all of them.

Comment: @kubanczyk Have you an advice related to this challenge? What would you recommend instead? Please share some knowlegde, thanks!

Comment: @Fabian I don't customize these files. Every complex command is a one-liner somewhere in my shell history or in a textual snippet file.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no straightforward solution, here are a few ideas though: [How to bring .vimrc around when I SSH?](https://serverfault.com/questions/33423/how-to-bring-vimrc-around-when-i-ssh)

Comment: Sounds like there is no easy way out of this. :/